# Stopping Domain Admin from seeing user profile/supplied pc

Tags: security

Silly question but i'm not sure if its possible.

I want to supply a PC to clients with a solution of mine that i don't want them to have access to, it needs to run certain tasks and scripts.

If i supply the PC to the client and load it onto their domain i don't event want the Administrator to be able to log into that PC.

Is there a way to block all access except for access by me to that PC on the domain with only my credentials?

I was thinking i could do it through "local users and group settings".

Regards
Gordon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The domain admin will have to join the PC to the domain, and thereby have full admin rights.

Local rights only apply to the PC and are trumped by domain.

Comment: i Suspected so. Thank you